DNS could not resolve selected hosts only
I have a problem on all machines in the network resolving specifically analytics.google.com host. I should state that every other host resolution works fine. I've tried using multiple different DNS servers, including Cloudflare (DoH), Quad9 (all of them), Google DNS to no avail. It's not related to the client machine or even operating system, since all of the machines in this network, including couple of PCs, Macs and mobile devices have the same issue.
C:\Users\An>nslookup analytics.google.com
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** dns.google can't find analytics.google.com: Non-existent domain

Despite that:
C:\Users\An>nslookup google.com
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:4001:808::200e
          172.217.16.142

I'm kind of lost after 3 days of trying to resolve an issue. Any help highly appreciated. Thanks.

Please test with a clean machine, as like MalwareBytes was know to block analytics.google.ca, so it can a security product that block the DNS request.

@greg-askew nslookup shows which DNS is used and in that case it was Google DNS 8.8.8.8 (for both requests). There is no new related information in ipconfig /all command output.

@yagmoth555 as I've mentioned in my original question, all machines in the network are affected, despite completely different setups and operating systems. They don't have security products installed on any of them.

@none32 I kept it vague, as 'security product', but your router too can have antimalware mechanist inside it.

Based on yagmoth555 lead, despite having no security products installed, the router had a module installed for blocking ads and malware. Since analytics.google.com has been used in ads delivery in almost any case, it seems that the whole domain has been blocked. Disabling that router module resolved an issue.
